# How to declare function with arguments being one of two types in Rust

Tags: rust

I have two struct types (non-real examples given here for simplicity):

```rust
pub struct EpochSigned {
    pub attr_a: u32,
    pub attr_b: u32,
    pub attr_c: u32
}

pub struct EpochUnsigned {
    pub attr_a: u32,
    pub attr_b: u32
}
```

As you can see, they are identical, for the exception of 1 attribute.

I've got logic involving these two structs, that repeats in a few places. I want to refactor it out into a separate function. The specific piece of logic does *not* work with the attribute that differs. Or in other words, it only works with `attr_a` and `attr_b` of either type.

So, in essence, this function I want to create would not make difference between the two types. But I don't know how to declare it, so it can work with either type.

In TypeScript I could do smth like:

```js
function myFn(epochSigned: EpochSigned | EpochUnsigned, epochUnsigned: EpochSigned | EpochUnsigned)
```

The problem is that the other functions that have the logic I want to refactor out, do work with the specific types, so I can't just use one type.

I'm sure this is a common scenario in any application, but I just don't know how to navigate it in Rust.

Comment: Usually you wrap this in an `enum` which describes both variants and that's the type you pass in. Alternatively, they could both implement some sort of `trait` which you can use instead. You may want to re-think your definitions here and instead have an `Epoch` base which could wrap both your signed/unsigned versions here, possibly by having optional fields, possibly by being an `enum`.

Comment: @tadman, you should make your comment into an answer!

Comment: @effect There's some implementation details here to cover, which anyone is welcome to do. The best I can offer now is general advice.

Comment: If `EpochSigned`'s fields are a superset of `EpochUnsigned`, you could encode that at the type-level by replacing all the common fields in `EpochSigned` by a single field with type `EpochUnsigned`. Then, your function could simply be defined for `EpochUnsigned`, and you would pass the field with that type if you wanted to "apply" it to an `EpochSigned`.

Answer (score 3):

The greatest flexibility is going to come from determining what common functionality the two have, describing that in a trait, and then having both structs implement that trait.

Following this strategy, you are then free to implement that trait for *any* type where it makes sense, and they will all be able to be passed into that function without modification to the function's signature or implementation.

It also leaves you free to write *other* functions which take values of a type that implement that trait.

Answer (score 3):

Per @tadman's comment, this seems like a classic use case for an enum. Depending on your preferences, you can either have tuple-like or struct-like enum variants to help track the different fields on each variant.

```rust
// tuple-like
pub enum Epoch {
    Signed(u32, u32, u32),
    Unsigned(u32, u32),
}

// struct-like
pub enum Epoch {
    Signed { attr_a: u32, attr_b: u32, attr_c: u32 },
    Unsigned { attr_a: u32, attr_b: u32 },
}
```

Depending on how the rest of your code is structured you can then either implement function directly on the enum, or by matching on the type in your calling code, doing the signed/unsigned specific stuff and then handing off to the signed agnostic code.

```rust
impl Epoch {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        match self {
            Epoch::Signed(a, b, c) => { /* do stuff */ }
            Epoch::Unsigned(a, b) => { /* do stuff */ }
        }
        // stuff that doesn't care about signedness
    }
}

fn use_epoch_enum(epoch: Epoch)  {
    epoch.do_something();
}
 
fn use_epoch_with_match(epoch: Epoch) {
    match epoch {
        Epoch::Signed(a, b, c) => { /* do stuff */ }
        Epoch::Unsigned(a, b) => { /* do stuff */ }
    }
    // stuff that doesn't care about signedness
}
```

You could also handle this via traits, using either generics or dynamic dispatch.

```rust
trait EpochTrait {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

struct SignedEpoch {
    // fields
}

impl EpochTrait for SignedEpoch {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

struct UnsignedEpoch {
    // fields
}

impl EpochTrait for UnsignedEpoch {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

fn use_epoch_generic<T: EpochTrait>(epoch: T) {
    epoch.do_something();
}

fn use_epoch_dynamic(epoch: Box<dyn EpochTrait>) {
    epoch.do_something();
}
```

Dynamic dispatch will require the trait to be [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) and be boxed, but will* have better compilation times as monomorphization is not required; generics will* have better runtime performance, but may take longer to compile.

- 'will' is an oversimplification here, but are general guidelines, as always if either runtime or compilation times are critical, benchmarking is better than relying on general wisdom.

As for the decision between enum and trait, the general guidance is to think about whether you can exhaustively define the variants ahead of time. In this case, it seems like Epoch can only ever be Signed or Unsigned, so an enum makes sense - you can define it ahead of time and not have to think about it.

If it was something where you don't know how many possible variants there are ahead of time, or you're doing something like writing a library and want to allow your users maximum flexibility the trait is the better choice.

The other thing that's worth considering is how different the logic between the two variants is - having two separate impls of a trait might be easier to follow if there are some important differences; but if the bulk of the code is the same, then an impl block on an enum with a match to handle the differences might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative the the ones already suggested is to refactor the common field into a struct and embed it into the two structs. Then your function can take this struct, which is compatible with both structs.

Example:

```rust
pub struct Common {
    pub attr_a: u32,
    pub attr_b: u32,
}

pub struct EpochSigned {
    pub common: Common,
    pub attr_c: u32,
}

pub struct EpochUnsigned {
    pub common: EpochCommon,
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. Can you give a code example?

Comment: @Milkncookiez Edited.